# A word/expression that encapsulates all your familiar people

Tags: word-request, expressions

As we all know, **acquaintances** are the people whom we know but do not know well and therefore they are not considered as a friend.

We have a term which can encompass all the people we know, including: all the familiar people including friends, and people that comparing your close ones, you know them less.

As I know, "acquaintace" cannot be used in this sense, because it cannot encapsulate close people to you.

I wonder if there is a term/word/expression which can indicate such a meaning in current English.

Comment: "All the people I know" is probably the most common way to say this.  Did you specifically want an **idiom**, or just the most idiomatic way to say it?

Comment: Interesting @Andrew; come to think of it, I guess knowing both would be better. :)

Answer (score 4):

I think a good expression for this is *circle*, as in, "the people in my circle" or just "my circle". (See [definition 6 in Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/circle)). *Orbit* can be used in a similar way. It's like you are the sun in the "solar system" of people you know. You could also use *network* but that has a connotation of people who work with you or in your field. That word is better for business as opposed to personal relationships.

Comment: You can specify this as well:  *My circle of **friends***, *My circle of **acquaintances***, *My circle of **business contacts***, and so on. You can also specify the people in your **social circle**, although this may be limited to people you consider "peers".

Comment: Thank you @Andrew . I guess in spite of what dictionaries have mentioned, the word "acquantances" can cover a larger area of familiar people. I need you to let me know who can fall in this group? I.e. my relatives, my friends or people I somehow know and I'm familiar with them, can be counted as "my circle of acquaintances"?

Comment: @A-friend  "acquaintances" means "people you know" -- however, it usually includes the nuance "but who you would not call *friends*".

Comment: So @Andrew the word acquaintance would work for me! This is what I needed. Therefore all my relatives and people I knoe excepting close friends would be "my acquaintances" while dictionaries do not give me such information. Thank you very much for that Andrew. ;)

Comment: @A-friend  I don't think family count as "acquaintances" either, even if they are distant family.  It's more like people you come into contact with on a regular basis but who aren't related to you, and who you don't really consider to be *close*.  For example, most of my neighbors are *acquaintances*, but not *friends*.

Comment: Aha; I see @Andrew. It was better if you could post these points as an answer so that I could approve it as the answer to my question.

Comment: I agree with @Andrew - "acquaintances" are people who you know or have met a few times but don't know very well. Family wouldn't be included in this category. However, I have seen the word "friends" mean both what we normally consider "friends" (people close to you who are not family) as well as "family". Maybe this is an older sense of the word.